# Ler vários números de scanf separados por espaço

Tags: c, array

Estou precisando fazer um programa que recebe uma quantidade de elementos de um vetor, e depois cada elemento desse vetor, porém no mesmo `scanf` com espaços. Só que eu não sei como fazer isso, alguém pode me ajudar.

Exemplo:

```
3
1 2 3
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem de programação? "C" ?

Comment: Desculpe, é em C

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do que você fez, ficará mais fácil de alguém te ajudar.

Comment: ta no vetor e você quer ler? não entendi esse scanf defina melhor por favor.

Comment: Tipo, o usuario digita quantos elementos o vetor vai ter, e depois em um scanf tem que colocar esses elementos separados por um espaço.

Answer (score 2):

Se quer ler vários numeros separados de espaço, então quer ler tudo como uma `string` e basicamente fazer *split* sobre um determinado separador, neste caso o espaço. A forma mais fácil e nativa de fazer isso é utilizar [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/). Esta função lê uma parte de uma `string` até apanhar o separador indicado, e depois a partir do ultimo ponto é possível voltar a chamar para apanhar mais outro bocado.

Exemplo:

```
int quant;
scanf("%d", &quant);
int vetor[quant];
char nums[512]; //espaço para os numeros todos como um texto
scanf(" %[^\n]", nums); //lê todos os números como um texto
char *token = strtok (nums," "); //lê até ao primeiro espaço para a variavel token
int pos = 0; //posição para guardar os numeros no vetor começa em 0

while (token != NULL && pos < quant) {
    vetor[pos++] = atoi(token); //guarda o valor convertido em numero no vetor e avança
    token = strtok (NULL, " "); //lê até ao próximo espaço a partir de onde terminou
}
```

A conversão do texto para número foi feita com [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/). É tamabem importante reparar que os restantes `strtok` que não o primeiro, levam como primeiro parâmetro `NULL` para indicar que são continuações dos anteriores.

Agora bastaria usar o vetor de números:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; ++i){
    printf("%d\n", vetor[i]);
}
```

Que lhe dá a seguinte saida:

```
1
2
3
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/uMsmU8)

Comment: O que acontece se eu digitar mais de 512 caracteres?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Passa dos limites do espaço alocado e escreve em zona da memoria que não pertence ao vetor. Naturalmente pode colocar outro valor que ache razoável para o input que espera, como 1024, 2048, 4096,etc. Mas ai já começa a entrar noutro problema que já passou aqui noutras perguntas que é como ler "input ilimitado" em C. Apenas coloquei um que me pareceu razoável para  o exemplo de entrada que deu.

Comment: Existe input *limitado*? Quanto você espera que seja um tamanho de vetor _razoável_?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura "Quanto você espera que seja um tamanho de vetor razoável?" - Só você sabe dizer, afinal de contas você é que sabe para que o programa vai servir e o que ele vai fazer. "Existe input limitado?" - Como é que você lê uma string em C ? Não declara previamente o vetor de chars ? Tem de lá colocar o tamanho caso contrário rebenta o programa com um segmentation fault, logo não é ilimitado não. O limite depende do que lá escreveu.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Vale lembrar que pode sempre controlar se o input ultrapassou o tamanho definido quer com `scanf(" %512[^\n]` e fazendo um teste adicional para saber se o ultimo caratere lido foi `\n` ou trocando o `scanf` por um `fgets` que até seria o mais aconselhado. Apenas não o fiz para tentar manter a resposta simples.

Comment: Onde eu acho referência sobre `[^\n]`? Isso é normatizado/recomendado? Qualquer compilador C suporta isso?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura A referência esta na documentação do `scanf` mesmo. Pode ver [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). O mais recomendado é mesmo utilizar `fgets` que foi excluído pela restrição da pergunta, ainda assim se validado face ao tamanho não tem qualquer problema. Todos os compiladores suportam isso sim.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem você está tentando ler números e inserir em um vetor, sendo que estas tentando fazer essa leitura com mais de um número... 
Segue o exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 3
 int main()
 {
 int i,x;
 int v[N];
 scanf("%d %d",&i,&x);
 v[0]=i;
 v[1]=x;
 v[2]=0;

 }
```

Esse é um pequeno exemplo... scanf("%d %d",&x,&i);
Segue os critérios de sempre % com o tipo de variável no caso d ou i de decimal ou inteiro (%d) repete mais de uma vez se for mais que uma variável e depois usa os &.

Comment: Quase isso, só que tipo, eu não sei quantos elementos o usuário quer, então se por exemplo ele quiser 10 elementos, o código ficaria muito grande. Queria saber se tem alguma forma de diminuir isso.

Comment: Vetores são finitos, tu irá ter um número de espaço pré determinado. E o scanf tu não precisa fazer tudo junto no mesmo, faz com um laço de repetição e le normal. Não pode?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não consegui achar jeito de passar um vetor ou um ponteiro para vetor, para um `scanf`. Veja se desta forma te ajuda:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pegaVetor(int* vetor, int qtd)
{
    int i;

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Entre o vetor, abaixo:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < qtd; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
}

double media(int* vetor, int qtd)
{
    int i;
    int soma = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < qtd; ++i)
    {
        soma += vetor[i];
    }

    return (double)soma / qtd;
}

int main()
{
    int* vetor;
    int n;

    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o numero de elementos (0 para sair): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n)
        {
            vetor = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
            pegaVetor(vetor, n);
            printf("A media aritmetica do vetor e: %f\n", media(vetor, n));
            free(vetor);
        }
    } while (n);

    return 0;
}
```

Os possíveis delimitadores de tokens de entrada, para o `scanf`, são espaços em branco e/ou `Enter`s.